# How to connect to a Unix domain (AF_UNIX) socket in R language?

Tags: r, sockets

i have a requirement where i need to connect to a local file based unix domain [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)  from R . R by default has the make,read.socket(),socketConnection() functions which take host:port as arguments but not files . Is there any package through which i can connect to a file based unix local socket and read/write from it ?

Thanks
sanre6

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing the C language interface to sockets with the R representation.

If you need to connect to a C level socket, write C code and bind that to R via the `.C()` and (preferably) `.Call()` interface.  See the 'Writing R Extensions' manual for the C level interface to R, and possibly also the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) docs for a highler-level C++ interface on top of these.

Comment: yea i agree natively it has to use C to connect to these sockets . Was asking if there was any package available with R wrapped around these c functions ? i want to use R as a client to my java based socket server that i have done using http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/ , sorry if the question seems to be a bit vague :)

Comment: Peruse the r-devel mailing list archives -- socket interfaces come up every now and then though it is generally tricky as R is single-threaded.